# pandas DataFrame:: while copying value of record from last row of one dataframe to another dataframe showing error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```py
#trying to copy low value of last record into another temp dataframe


df_new = df_new.append(df_old.iloc[-1, df_old.columns.get_loc("low")])



o/p-->

TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

Comment: Please, format the code correctly so that people can understand what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved above issue..The solution is by converting the Numpy array into series with the help of Pandas method pd.Series.

temp_high= df_old.iloc[-1, df_old.columns.get_loc("high")]

temp_high= pd.Series(temp_high)

df_new = df_new .append(temp_high, ignore_index=True)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this. I do not have your data, but this works.

```
df_new = df_new.append(df_old.iloc[[-1]], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: solved above issue..The solution is by  converting the Numpy array into series with the help of Pandas method pd.Series..